# Understanding behavior of backreferencing in vim

Tags: regex, vim, vi, substitution

I have a file which contains this word:

> Word

when I execute this command:

```
:s/\(\w\)\+/#\1#/
```

I got `##` but as I know `\w` matches a character. Why I did not get it in backreferencing it ?

Now for this command

`:s/\(\w\)\{1,}/#\1#/` I got `#d#`. why it is the last character and not the first ?

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Your goal isn't really clear, so I'm not sure if I understood your question

Comment: I want to understand the behavior. why I got that ?

Comment: Ok, so I delete my answer as I must admit I have no idea why vim doesn't end capturing the "d". In my experience the vim regex engine isn't to be understood but just dealt with....

Comment: You are getting `#d#` in first regex also

Comment: @rock321987 What ? On what version of vim did you test?

Comment: @DenysSéguret its vim `version 7.4.52`

Comment: In vim version 7.4 on Ubuntu 15.10 I definitely get the same behavior than Sabrina (and it looks like a bug or one of the many "peculiarities" of the vim regex engine...)

Comment: I get `#d#` with every Vim I could get my hands on. What version do you use on what platform?

Comment: @DenysSéguret See **[`here`](http://gph.is/2i27TU9)**.. it seems to work

Comment: @DenysSéguret what is the meaning of real vim?I made that in ubuntu vim

Comment: @romainl vim 7.4 ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It works for me on vim 7.4 (Windows 7).

Comment: @romainl where are you ??

Comment: Unlike @DenysSéguret I can't reproduce this in Ubuntu 15.10, but I can reproduce it in 16.04 (7.4, patches 1-1689, extra patch 8.0.0056). Definitely seems like a bug in the build shipping with Ubuntu 16.04 (package version 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2).

Comment: Okay thanks for the share.

Comment: As the bug seems to have been fixed, and unless somebody wants to come with the bug report, this (good) question can probably be closed.

Comment: I am also getting this in vim 8 version. It may be a bug

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this with Vim 7.4.1689 (that ships with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but not any longer with Vim 8.0.55. `:set re=1` (i.e. switching back to the old regexp engine) fixes the problem, too. So, it seems to be a bug in the new regexp engine that in the meantime has been fixed.